# Using ASP.Net Core 2.2 Auth Cookies in old .Net Web Forms (aspx) site for SSO

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-core, webforms, single-sign-on, asp.net-core-2.2

TLDR: How can I get an Asp.Net Core 2.2 encrypted auth cookie understood by a legacy Web Forms app?

*The DR:*

I find myself in a situation where I'm trying to get a legacy Web forms (aspx) site to use an auth cookie set in the browser by a new and shiny .NET Core 2.2 MVC site. The Web Forms app in question is written in **Visual Basic**, the .Net Core app in **C#**. Everything is hosted by IIS/IIS Express (from Visual Studio).

The cookie appears to be set fine, and to make things easy (for now), all things are hosted on the same machine (My Windows 10 Professional Edition Dell XPS). The encryption/machine key for cookie encryption is in a well defined location on disk. The .Net Core app (Let's call it "Auth Portal" for now) is basically a front for AWS Cognito.

In Auth Portal, the cookie is configured like so in *Startup.cs*:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        var keyDir = Configuration["AuthSettings:CookieEncryptionKeyDir"];
        services.AddDataProtection()
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keyDir))
            .SetApplicationName(Configuration["ApplicationName"]);

        services.AddCognitoIdentity();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IAmazonCognitoIdentityProvider),
            _ => new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2)); // Oh no you know I'm using Sydney!

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie();

        services
            .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                var parseSucceeded = int.TryParse(Configuration["AuthSettings:CookieExpiryHours"],
                    out var cookieExpiry);
                if (!parseSucceeded) _log.LogError("Failed to parse from configuration auth cookie expiry value");

                parseSucceeded = bool.TryParse(Configuration["AuthSettings:SSLCookieOnly"], out var secureCookieOnly);
                var securePolicy = secureCookieOnly ? CookieSecurePolicy.Always : CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                if (!parseSucceeded) _log.LogError("Failed to parse from configuration cookie security policy");

                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(cookieExpiry);
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.LoginPath = Configuration["AuthSettings:LoginUrl"];
                options.LogoutPath = Configuration["AuthSettings:LogoutUrl"];
                options.Cookie.Domain = Configuration["AuthSettings:TrustedDomains"];
                options.Cookie.Name = Configuration["AuthSettings:CookieName"];
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = securePolicy;
            });

        services
            .Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            });

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardLimit = 2;
            options.ForwardedForHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-For-Auth-Portal";
        });
```

In the Web Forms app, I'm replacing the existing default sql auth. This is where the online resources seem to dry up. I can make a custom membership provider which I have done easily. But it does not (understandably) understand the existing cookie out of the box, even when I set the cookie name in the forms auth settings

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="60" name="my.sso.cookie" requireSSL="false" path="/"  />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="CognitoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CognitoMembershipProvider" type="TheOldWebFormsApp.Authentication.CognitoMembershipProvider" applicationName="MyWebForms" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="3" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="8" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

As I have found it will just overwrite the existing cookie which I'm assuming is because it deems and un-understandable cookie as a non-existent one.

I guess this a very long winded way of asking how can i get this old Web Forms app to accept and decrypt the Auth Portal cookie?

Cheers~!

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to use SSO with the web form apps, but I am not seeing how you handle a redirect to the identity provider you have from your webform app, that can give a better idea of how you are handling the loggin option from the webform. At the same time your identity provider should identify that webform app as a trusted application. What you are presenting is only the configuration for the authentication mode

Comment: @Zinov In this scenario, my Auth Portal is the effective Identity Provider. The Auth Portal and Webforms app are on the same domain, with the cookie set to trust the root domain (for now). For all intents and purposes, the auth cookie is already in the browser memory and IS being attached with each request to the webform app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. ASP.NET Core uses an entirely different methodology to encrypt cookies than ASP.NET does. The latter is based on a "machine key", but ASP.NET Core use data protection providers and a key ring. The two are fundamentally incompatible, so even if you can "share" the cookie, such that each one sees it, one will not be able to decrypt the cookie set by the other.

It *is* possible to successfully share cookies with ASP.NET MVC 5, but that's because it makes use of OWIN, and the data protection stuff is OWIN compatible. As such, even though MVC 5 also uses machine keys natively, it can be made to use data protection instead, and then it can share the same data protection key store with an ASP.NET Core site. However, Web Forms does not support OWIN, so the same cannot be achieved there. In short, this a complete no-go.

An alternative, perhaps, is relying on a centralized identity provider, such as Identity Server, Auth0, Azure AD, etc. With such a solution, it's not necessary to share cookies as each site authorizes independently with the provider, but the same user account can be used. The actual login happens at the identity provider, then each site authorized with that identity provider is given the identity from the identity provider and can then set their own cookies or whatever with that.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I suspected as much. I guess I'll devote my energies to other solutions and/or methodologies. 
There is a desire _at the moment_ not to completely rely on a 3rd party provider.

Comment: I just wanted to update this, It IS possible to have the cookie shared between the 2 worlds. I'll see if I can find the time to detail what had to be done.

Comment: @JohnGeddes - Would you be able to share any details (any at all?!) on the solution you came up with? I am working on the exact same "challenge"... I have a massive web forms site that will start to migrate over to a .NET Core site, but we only want a single login.  The cookie itself doesn't have to be shared, I suppose, just a way to establish a single sign on.

Comment: @MargoNoreen I no longer have access to the codebase where I was implementing this but I'll give my best from memory (working on something else now).
I focused on implementing OWIN in VB.NET Webforms (A few blog post exist about this). I then relied on the fact that C# and VB are quite interchangeable and translated my .net core classes into vb (such as my startup.cs to startup.vb). If you find yourself installing a whole bunch of interop packages, you're probably on the right track.