# Use the same cookie across asp.net webforms site and .net core 3.1 site

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, cookies, webforms

I am running a asp.net Framework 4.8 webforms project and a asp.net core 3.1 project on the same domain with separate sub-domains for each project.

I would like to be able have users login with .net core identity on the new site which would assign them a cookie and let that cookie authenticate them on the older webforms application using Owin Middleware.

From the research I've done it seems like this is not possible using webforms authentication and .net core. But, Is it possible using microsoft.aspnet.identity and Owin middleware? Could I somehow decrypt the .net core cookie on the webforms site using the Owin middleware and use it's claims to set a aspnet.identity cookie for the webforms site, or just inject those claims into the old app so I can have my HttpContext User Identity thought the app?

Supposedly [John Geddes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4377978/john-geddes) Found a solution but didn't have time to share what he did (See his comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699395/using-asp-net-core-2-2-auth-cookies-in-old-net-web-forms-aspx-site-for-sso)). He said he used Owin on the .net framework webforms app but didn't give anymore detail.

This is my .net core startup class

```csharp
 public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          
            services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            })
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SJRContext>()
               .AddSignInManager<SJRSignInManager<User>>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
               .AddTokenProvider<CustomTwoFactorTokenProvider<User>>("TwoFactorAuthToken");

            //cookie is added here
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddCookie(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                    cfg.LoginPath = @"/Account/Login";
                    cfg.LogoutPath = @"/Account/Logout";
                    cfg.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    cfg.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                    cfg.Cookie.Domain = Configuration.GetSection("AppDomain").Value;
                }); 

            //More service set up here...

            services.AddSession();
        }

        public void OnShutdown()
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            //More middleware here...

            app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
            {
                //Get and set cookie exp date according to ip address and client device here

                //Go to next middleware
                await next();

            });


            //More middleware here....

            app.UseAuthorization();

           
        }
    }
```

This is the Web.config where the cookie is set on the asp.net framework 4.8 webforms

```xml
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!-- Set login to login page for development -->
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

And this is my web.release.config file used to override the above file when in release mode

```xml
 <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!-- Set login to .net core login page for production (Release)-->

      <forms loginUrl="https://MyDotNetCoreSubDomain.SharedDomain.com/Account/Login" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" name=".AspNetCore.Identity.Application" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" timeout="4320" domain=".SharedDomain.com" slidingExpiration="true" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Hi @BoMerican,as the answer said,it is impossible to share cookie between web forms and asp.net core.

Comment: Rena, Yes, but If you look at @JohnGeddes Comment on that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699395/using-asp-net-core-2-2-auth-cookies-in-old-net-web-forms-aspx-site-for-sso) he ended up figuring out how to do it using **Owin middleware**. That is what I am trying to figure out now. I would like to slowly upgrade my old webforms app without forcing users to login to both apps separately.

Comment: @Rena I updated my question to be a little more clear with the direction I am trying to go.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps), this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNTuoWoRlYo), and with some understanding of how cookies work through other research. I will outline the process to make this work showing my code as examples.

Summery: Simply put, cookie authentication encrypts principals (user identity) on a cookie (or multiple cookies using cookie chunks) and gives that cookie to the client (user). Every time the client make a request to the server they include the cookie and the server needs to decrypt that cookie. To do this across multiple web apps we store the encryption key somewhere where both apps can access it and use identity to handle decryption. Please note you need to secure this key because the security of your app depends on it.

Configure startup of .net core 3.1 site. This should work for .net core 2.x too.

1. Set up identity

```
 services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
 {
   cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
 })
   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SJRContext>()
   .AddSignInManager<SJRSignInManager<User>>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

2. Set up dataprotection (using that encryption key)

```
services.AddDataProtection()
   .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration.GetSection("SharedCookie:CookieKeys").Value))
.SetApplicationName(Configuration.GetSection("SharedCookie:CookieApplicationName").Value);
```

3. Set up cookie (in my case I set the cookie domain and used different sub-domains for each website).

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
{
    opt.Cookie.Name = Configuration.GetSection("SharedCookie:CookieName").Value;
    opt.Cookie.Domain = Configuration.GetSection("AppDomain").Value;
    opt.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

Next I needed to configure my old .net framework 4.8 webforms site to stop using webforms authentication and use the owin middleware instead. This way I could use identity to decrypt the shared cookie.

To do this I needed to create a Startup class and startup.auth class This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNTuoWoRlYo) walked me through this.

1. Here is my start up class

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Owin

<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Startup))>
Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        ConfigureAuth(app)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that this part of the code tells owin to use this as the start up class:

```
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Startup))>
```

2. In my startup.auth class I put all my authentication logic.

This part gets complicated and can be easy to copy and paste and not understand what is going on. This part of the process is explained in the Microsoft walk through [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#share-authentication-cookies-between-aspnet-4x-and-aspnet-core-apps) but to sum it up, you want to set the authentication type, cookie name, application name, and keys to be the same across both sites. Also, make sure the login and logout path of this cookie is pointed towards the .net core login and logout path so that can be the one place all authentication cookies are handed out.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Interop
Imports Owin


Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions With
        {
            .AuthenticationType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieAuthenticationType"),
            .CookieName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieName"),
            .LoginPath = New PathString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("workordersWebAddress") + "Account/Login"),
            .LogoutPath = New PathString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("workordersWebAddress") + "Account/Logout"),
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider With
            {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                    validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            },
            .TicketDataFormat = New AspNetTicketDataFormat(
                New DataProtectorShim(
                    DataProtectionProvider.Create(New DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieKeys")),
                        Function(builder) builder.SetApplicationName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieApplicationName"))
                    ).CreateProtector(
                        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieAuthenticationType"),
                        "v2"
                    )
                )
            ),
            .CookieManager = New ChunkingCookieManager()
        })
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please note I am using my web.config file on the webforms site and appsettings.json file
on my .net core site to store my cookie name, cookie authentication type, cookie key locations and application name.

Before this will build you will need to make sure all nuget packages are installed and you have your identity set up correctly on the webforms app. I do not intend on using Identity and roles throughout the webforms app so I will show you how to get this working for cookies only.

Create an application user. Notice I do not set any properties. I am only inheriting the properties from the IdentityUser object.

```
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework

Public Class ApplicationUser
    Inherits IdentityUser

    Public Async Function GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ByVal manager As UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)) As Task(Of ClaimsIdentity)
        ' The authenticationType must match the one defined in 
        ' CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        Dim userIdentity = Await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(Me, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CookieName"))

        ' Add custom user claims here
        Return userIdentity
    End Function
End Class
```

Next create usermanager.

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin

Public Class ApplicationUserManager
    Inherits UserManager(Of ApplicationUser)
    Public Sub New(ByVal store As IUserStore(Of ApplicationUser))
        MyBase.New(store)

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Create(ByVal options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of ApplicationUserManager), ByVal context As IOwinContext) As ApplicationUserManager
        Dim store = New UserStore(Of ApplicationUser)(context.Get(Of WorkordersDatabase.SJContext)())
        Dim manager = New ApplicationUserManager(store)
        Return manager
    End Function
End Class
```

After you have your identity user and usermanager pointed towards the same dbcontext that your .net core app is pointed towards you should now be able to decrypt those cookies on both sites.